# variable-watches stopped working in vs2010 / C# debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've got a major problem here.
Whenever I debug a C#-solution, set a breakpoint and try to inspect a variable-content nothing happens. I can't see it when I drag it into a watch-window ("unable to evaluate the expression.") - the Autos and Locals windows are just empty, Immediate Window just tells me "Unable to evaluate the expression") and even the memory-windows just give me "Unable to evaluate the expression.".

When I switch to F# everything works just fine - VB.net is gone too.

I guess this has something to do with the Async CTP I tried to install.

What I tried so far:
- Deinstalled the CTP
- Tried to repair the VS2010 installation
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled VS2010

Not working - after reinstall VS is starting as ever (with the problems and all settings/installed plugins)

So what? Wipe the system? I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Async CTP causes this problem. Try to install SP1 Beta. This solved the problem.